# how to filter from ADODB.Recordset in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am using ADODB.Recordset in my vba program, loading all record from table to recordset and want to filter record inside the loop based on loop(i value).

I am using below code to filter record from recordset:

```
for (dim i as integer = 1 to 10)
    rsContacts.Filter = "Name = '" & Cell(i,1) & "' and Id = '" & Cell(i,2)& "'"
next
```

It's filtering properly returning one record when `i = 1` but when `i = 2` recordset doesn't have any record. How can filter record but want to keep full recordset so that it will filter properly?

Comment: Before anyone would be willing to read your question and try to help, please format it properly.

Comment: `for (dim i as integer = 1 to 10)` is a syntax error in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add code to move to the first record.
 `rsContacts.MoveFirst`

Another suggestion would be to clear the filter beforehand
 `rsContacts.Filter = adFilterNone`

Answer (score 0):

Before the next step in the `For` - `Next` cycle, try clear filtering by

```
rsContacts.Filter=""
```

or

```
rsContacts.Filter=adFilterNone
```